# Add a column with each dataset's name of multiple files, in R

Tags: r

In a group of files, I want to add a column in each of the files that all contains the name of the file, so that when I combine the all the files, it can still refer to the specific file it comes from.

The code I already have and want to build on is this.

```
file.list <- list.files(pattern='*.xlsx')
df.list <- sapply(file.list, read_excel, simplify=FALSE)

price_per_cts_range <- bind_rows(df.list)
```

Comment: Your `.id = "filename"` in `bind_rows` after naming the `df.list` i.e. `names(df.list) <- file.list; bind_rows(df.list, .id = "filename")`

Comment: Hi @akrun, I have the same problem and your solution answered my question... However, what if you want to load a specific number of rows? e.g. `file= read_excel(file.xlsx", range = "J9:Q10")`. I am trying this: `df.list <- sapply(file.list, read_excel(range = "J9:Q10"), simplify=FALSE)` but I get this error: `Error in check_file(path) : argument "path" is missing, with no default`. If I remove range="J9:Q10" it works perfectly.

Comment: Okay, I found the way to do it, sorry. The solution would be this one: `df.list=lapply(file.list, function(x) read_excel(x,range = "J9:Q10"))`